# Using Arcade for ArcGIS Pro Dictionary style

Tags: arcgis-pro, dictionary, arcade

I successfully created a new dictionary style that adds a symbol if a value exists (boolean); trying to add more symbols if values in other fields exist, but no luck.  I am new to Arcade, so probably missing something obvious.

My field names are `featured`, `stocked`, and `ofba_acces`.
My symbol key names are `Featured`, `Trout Stock`, and `Boat Ramp`.

My dictionary configuration looks like:

```
{
  "configuration": [{
      "name": "text",
      "value": "ON",
      "domain": ["ON", "OFF"],
      "info": "indicates if the text is rendered"
    }
  ],
  "symbol": ["Featured", "Trout Stock", "Boat Ramp"],
  "text": ["name"]
}
```

Then my dictionary script looks like:

```
// conventions: 
// Symbolizes fishing points with symbols clockwise
// $xyz: attribute (received as string)

// calculate the semi-colon delimited list of keys.
var keys;

// Check if the 'featured' symbol should be shown.
if($featured == "-1"){
// Add this key to the list.
keys = keys + "Featured;";
}

// Check if the 'stocked' symbol should be shown.
if($stocked == "-1"){
// Add this key to the list.
keys = keys + "Trout Stock;";
}

// Check if the 'ofba' symbol should be shown.
if($ofba_acces == "-1"){
// Add this key to the list.
keys = keys + "Boat Ramp;";
}

// See if text should be displayed.
var showLabels = $text != 'OFF';

// Add the label key if text is on.
if (showLabels) {
  keys = keys + "label-name;";
}
// Return string of keys.
return keys;
```

The scripts worked with just the `Featured` category, but not when I add others.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the values in your point layer's table? The only thing I can think of is that you're values in your fields aren't "-1"? That being said too, you may have an integer field, in which case the field wouldn't be equal to "-1" and instead just -1.